# Improve CASE select performance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, performance, case, query-performance

I have the following query which is taking up to 2 seconds to run on a data set of less than 100K rows.

My SQL is very rusty but this just looks like it's doing a ton more work than it should. Can anyone offer some pointers on where to look to speed this up?

```
SELECT
    a.AddressID,
    IsPrincipal = CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.Setting s WHERE s.SettingValue = a.AddressID AND s.SettingDefinitionID = 3 AND s.ProfileID = 1)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END,
    IsPickUp = CASE
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.AddressRole ar WHERE ar.AddressID = a.AddressID AND ar.[AddressRoleTypeID] = 2)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END,
    IsSender = CASE
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.AddressRole ar WHERE ar.AddressID = a.AddressID AND ar.[AddressRoleTypeID] = 3)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END,
            IsDelivery = CASE
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.AddressRole ar WHERE ar.AddressID = a.AddressID AND ar.[AddressRoleTypeID] = 4)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END,
    IsReceiver = CASE
                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.AddressRole ar WHERE ar.AddressID = a.AddressID AND ar.[AddressRoleTypeID] = 5)
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
            END
        FROM dbo.[Address] AS a
        WHERE a.MFTID = '12345'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing a lookup like that for each row, you could join the `AddressRole` and `Setting` tables like this:

```
SELECT
    a.AddressID,
    IsPrincipal = Max(iif(s.SettingValue Is Not Null, 1, 0)),
    IsPickUp = Max(iif(ar.AddressRoleTypeID = 2, 1, 0)),
    IsSender = Max(iif(ar.AddressRoleTypeID = 3, 1, 0)),
    IsDelivery = Max(iif(ar.AddressRoleTypeID = 4, 1, 0)),
    IsReceiver = Max(iif(ar.AddressRoleTypeID = 5, 1, 0))
  FROM dbo.[Address] AS a
  Left Join dbo.Setting As s
    On a.AddressID = s.SettingValue
    And s.SettingDefinitionID = 3
    And s.ProfileID = 1
  Left Join dbo.AddressRole As ar
    On a.AddressID = ar.AddressID
  WHERE a.MFTID = '12345'
  Group By a.AddressID;
```

This should reduce the number of joins performed, and not change the cardinality of the resultset.

I added the `MAX` so that I could do a `GROUP BY`, since I fully expect that there might be more than one row in the `AddressRole` table for each row in the `Address` table. This way we maintain the cardinality as being the same as the `Address` table, but we can see if any of the rows in the `AddressRole` contained the value of `AddressRoleTypeID` that we were looking for.

The `MAX` and `GROUP BY` aren't needed if the subqueries of your original query without the `TOP` return a single row.